# trying to expose my Service layer as WCF

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding

I have my service layer, entities and DTOS in a separeted assembly called CCL.Data

The problem:

All My application is referencing the service layer directly using interfaces and IoC.

For example, I have an interface in my CCL.Data assembly called ICustomerService it depends on ICustomerRepository that depends on MyContext.  All my application is referencing ICustomerService to call its methods....... so far no problem.

So I created a WCF Project.... referencing CCL.Data in this project....

I create a new Service, but int this case below, I would need to change all points in my application that call ICustomerService to WCFCustomerServiceClient, does exists a better way without cause a big impact in my project?

```
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IWCFCustomerService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        CustomerDTO GetCustomerById(int id);
    }

    public class WCFCustomerService : IWCFCustomerService
    {
        ICustomerService _customerService;
        public WCFCustomerService() 
        {
            MyContext context = new MyContext();
            ICustomerRepository customerRep = new CustomerRepository(context);
            _customerService = new CustomerService(customerRep);
        }

        public CustomerDTO GetCustomerById(int id)
        {
            return _customerService.GetCustomerById(id);
        }

    }
```

Tks,
William

Comment: I´ll do that. I wouldn´t like my assembly depending on System.ServiceModel.... But i have no choice.....thank you

Comment: Ive reposted comment as an answer since it seemed to help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you need to redefine IWCFCustomerService in place of ICustomerService? Is it not possible just to add ServiceContract attributes to your original ICustomerService interface (they will just get ignored by non WCF code)?  (Its true that this does give you a dependancy on ServiceModel - but I cant see a way out of that).

Note also that if you use a ServiceRefernce to generate proxy code then the code generated will include a your service interface in different namespace for use clientside.  Its worth noting that your not abliged to use that version of the interface (which could be annoying if you have a proxy and not proxy implimentation) but can still use the org interface definition either from a dll or compiled into your client.